# Android, How to call onCreate() explicitly from other method?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to call onCreate(Bundle cicici); from other method then i am getting "NullPointerException", so please guide me how can i call the onCreate() from another method().

```
    public void moreFriendsButtonClick(int id)
{
    contentId= id;
    onCreate(tempBundle);
}
```

Here i am passing int value, and

```
tempBundle=savedInstanceState;
```

and after that i am getting NullPointerException

Comment: Why do you need this? If you want to call some code that is inside your `onCreate` then move that code to some function named `onCreateHelper` and call both from your `onCreate` and from all other places you need.

Comment: @inazaruk - This should be an answer :)

Comment: here i make i TabActivity class and one of tab have some buttons, and i want to click on that specific button and the Activity page regarding to that button, should be display into Tab contentView area (Frame Layout).  if i am not doing like this then called Activity taking full screen... This is the reason.. so please guide me...

Comment: in document they said, we should not call lifecycle methods directly.

Answer (score 5):

you should create the bundle again. savedInstanceState is local to onCreate method.
try

```
Bundle tempBundle = new Bundle();
onCreate(tempBundle);
```

It should work.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

```
onCreate(new Bundle());
```