# I have an activity with recycler view adapter class, when button clicked in adapter class I want to refresh the main activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with RecyclerView.Adapter class. RecyclerView contains button. When click that button I want to change a value defined in main activity and display it in TextView that also defined in main activity , otherwise  I want to refresh the activity.

I already tried some code like:

- [Android, How to call onCreate() explicitly from other method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492196/android-how-to-call-oncreate-explicitly-from-other-method?rq=1)
- [How to restart the onCreate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150014/how-to-restart-the-oncreate-function/7150118#7150118)

Comment: try Activity.recreate()?

Comment: is recreate an in builld method?

Comment: use startActivityResult and got result on onActivityResult in mainActivity

Comment: I suppose something wrong with your design. In most cases you MUST NOT recreate Activity by yourself. Could you   clarify for what purposes do you need this?

Comment: send a instance of the activity into adapter class. write a public method in the activity class. in that method change a value in textview or refresh your activity which clicking on button.

Comment: I'm a beginner in this field so can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @alisun i defined a textview in my activity... by using a method i set a value in that textview..when button clicked in adapter class i want to change the textview data

Comment: Is recycler view on main activity??? @ArunRappaiC

Comment: @JoyHard yes, i defined recycler view in main activity...

Comment: try Intent  and call in onclicklistner or you can implement button in main activity

Comment: @jigarsavaliya by using intent the activity finish and come up...that works  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class));
                            finish();   but i need to know that another method i have more buttons ... so when button clicked each time i want to do this

Comment: @Arun Rappai C make static method  in mainActivity where changes take place and call it in listner

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to recreate Activity in this case. The best solution would be:

1. Declare an interface.
2. Implement it in Activity(here implement your updates to TextView, etc.).
3. Pass object that implements the interface to your adapter.
4. Call the method on this interface in adapter.

Here is example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720879/2528967

Answer (score 0):

```
YourActivity extends Activity implements YourAdapter.ClickCallback{

@override
oncreate(Bundle bundle){
 // initialize views 
 YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(this);
 // do something with your adapter
}

@Override
public void updateView(){
//update your views here
}   

}

//In Recycler Adapter pass ClickCallBack As parameter
class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

 private ClickCallBack clickCallBack;

 public YourAdapter(ClickCallBack clickCallBack){
 this.clickCallBack=clickCallBack;
 }

 //ClickCallback Interface
interface ClickCallBack {
 void updateView();
}

 //In your ButtonClick
  clickCallBack.updateView();

}
```

You can also add parameters in updateView method.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an instance of those TextView through constructor and update the value there in the Adaptor. That would be the easiest way.